# What happened to \bfdefault and \bfseries in the newest TeX Live 2019?

Tags: texlive-2019

I update the TeX Live 2019 on my computer today. Then the behavior of `\bfdefault` and `\bfseries` changed, see the next MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bfdefault\\
{\fontseries{\bfdefault}\selectfont TEXT}\\
{\bfseries TEXT}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result before updating:

[image]

The `\bfdefault` was `bx` and it changed to `b`. 
The `\bfseries` is not equivalent to `\fontseries{\bfdefault}\selectfont` after updating. 
Is this a bug? Or something else?

Comment: It is intentional.  See ltnews31.pdf.

Comment: Or https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is an important change.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Post an answer?