# beton stopped working with new TeXlive

Tags: fonts, bold, warnings, updating, texlive-2020

I used `beton` package, with `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sbc}` in accordance with next-to-last paragraph of https://texfaq.org/FAQ-concrete (for section titles and theorem heads, among other things).

Since I upgraded TeXlive, my bold substitution doesn't work. `pdflatex` says (for every usage of bold, about few hundreds of them):

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ccr/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/ccr/bx/n' instead
```

It's probably related to this question: [What happened to \bfdefault and \bfseries in the newest TeX Live 2019?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526999/what-happened-to-bfdefault-and-bfseries-in-the-newest-tex-live-2019) However, since I don't know even what the previous command was actually doing, and really did try to read latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf but found it completely impenetrable, I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me?

Here is a minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beton}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sbc}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a}
\end{document}
```

In previous TeXlive, I get no warning, and semibold a.
In new TeXlive, I get a warning, and a bold a.

Comment: only if you show a complete example.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that the links would be enough to understand what's going on. A _complete_ example is a book of 250 pages, I doubt you want to see that. :-) A _minimal_ example is now given above. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the bold font like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beton}
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{sbc} 
\begin{document}
a \textbf{a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(But I'm not really convinced *"that the Computer Modern Sans Serif demibold condensed fonts are an adequate substitute"* as claimed by the faq.)

Comment: Not to mention that the main fonts are only available in bitmap form. In any case, a document in Concrete Roman should never use boldface.

Comment: Very nice, and now it works in new TeXlive. However, it doesn't work in old (official) ones. :-/ Do I really need to do version sniffing in 2020? Is it so hard to have at least one version where both commands work?

Comment: You can test if `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault` is defined and setup  the code accordingly. Or you can use latexrelease to fall back to the old code. But I don't see how the code should be able to detect automatically that you want it to interpret your \renewcommand "as code in old style"